# Unable to get result for customer segmentation

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am doing RFM analysis in pandas. I have calculated the RFM Score successfully. However unable to create the customer segmentation based on RFM score. I attached the snippets of codes

```
best=list(rfm.loc[rfm['Rfm_Score']=="333".index])
lost_cheap=list(rfm.loc[rfm['Rfm_Score']=="111".index])
lost=list(rfm.loc[rfm['Rfm_Score']=="133"].index)
lost_almost=list(rfm['Rfm_Score']=="233".index)
for i in rfm.index:
 if i in lost_cheap:
    rfm.Segment.iloc[i]='LCC'
elif i in lost:
    rfm.Segment.iloc[i]='LC'
elif i in best:
    rfm.Segment.iloc[i]='BC'
elif i in lost_almost:
    rfm.Segment.iloc[i]='LA'
else:
    rfm.Segment.iloc[i]='Others'
```

It is showing the following error

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
10         rfm.Segment.iloc[i]='LA'
11     else:
---> 12         rfm.Segment.iloc[i]='Others'

~\anaconda3\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **getattr**(self, name)
5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
5275
5276     def **setattr**(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Segment'

[image: rfm dataframe]

Comment: Can you provide a short sample of what your `rfm` DataFrame looks like?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of my codes

Comment: If you want to populate `rfm.Segment`, you'll have to first instantiate `rfm['Segment'] = np.nan` or some other default value - Then your code should work fine. I would recommend vectorizing your approach though - looping through Pandas DataFrames is usually slow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have followed the second option i.e vectorizing approach.